# How to keep a label in one place inside a resizable and scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I have a resizable div that has more content than its size allows. So the user has to scroll through the content. I need to put a floating label that stays in one place inside the div as the user scrolls or resizes the div.

```
<div id="pane1" class="ui-layout-center">Top</div>
<div id="pane2" class="ui-layout-south">
    <span class="my_label">My Label</span>
    A lot of content
</div>
```

This is actually very similar to the floating labels on JSFiddle, but without the editor. I'm using jQuery UI Layout.

How do I keep **My Label** in one place?

Here is the problem on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/getvictor/hC6jP/2/

Comment: I believe `position: fixed` is basically what you're after.

Comment: @ultranaut, the div is resizable, so I need the label position to be relative to the top of the div.

Comment: @ultranaut is right, since your span is inside the container, it will move with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fixed positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/hC6jP/13/), or absolute positioning by placing the label outside the pane.

```
.my_label {
    border: solid 2px #FF0000;
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
    position: fixed;    // absolute -> fixed
    margin-left:1em;    // remove top/left positioning, and add left margin instead
                        //   note: left is still easy to work with
}
```

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky: `right:10px;`, but because of the scroll, probably `18px` or higher

Answer (score 0):

The CSS element you looking for was position fixed, i.e

```
Position: fixed;
```

[JS Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/hC6jP/12/)

And maybe that what you wanted

[JS Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/hC6jP/10/)